# JSON numeric root to generic name

Tags: c#, json, vb.net

I have a JSON file which looks like this.

```
{
  "1000": {
    "id": 1000,
    "name": "Clothes, Shoes and Bags",
    "path_from_root": [
      {
        "id": 1000,
        "name": "Clothes, Shoes and Bags"
      }
    ],
    "children_categories": [
      {
        "id": 1001,
        "name": "Accessories"
      },
      {
        "id": 2422,
        "name": "Athletic Shoes"
      },
      {
        "id": 2303,
        "name": "Baby Clothes"
      },
      {
        "id": 2115,
        "name": "Backpacks"
      },
      {
        "id": 1071,
        "name": "Bags"
      },
      {
        "id": 2105,
        "name": "Bags and Purses"
      },
      {
        "id": 2087,
        "name": "Children&#039;s Outfits"
      },
      {
        "id": 2051,
        "name": "Coats, Jackets and Vests"
      },
      {
        "id": 3192,
        "name": "Dresses and Skirts"
      },
      {
        "id": 3336,
        "name": "Glasses"
      },
      {
        "id": 2249,
        "name": "Others"
      },
      {
        "id": 2092,
        "name": "Overalls"
      },
      {
        "id": 1366,
        "name": "Pants, Shorts &amp; Bermudas"
      },
      {
        "id": 3191,
        "name": "School Uniforms"
      },
      {
        "id": 1894,
        "name": "Shirts"
      },
      {
        "id": 2353,
        "name": "Shoes"
      },
      {
        "id": 2417,
        "name": "Suits"
      },
      {
        "id": 2139,
        "name": "Swimwear"
      },
      {
        "id": 1979,
        "name": "T-shirts and Blouses"
      },
      {
        "id": 2254,
        "name": "Underwear and Lingerie"
      }
    ],
    "attributes_required": false,
    "max_pictures_per_item": 12,
    "max_title_length": 60,
    "max_price": null,
    "min_price": null,
    "listing_allowed": false
  },
  "1001": {
    "id": 1001,
    "name": "Accessories",
    "path_from_root": [
      {
        "id": 1000,
        "name": "Clothes, Shoes and Bags"
      },
      {
        "id": 1001,
        "name": "Accessories"
      }
    ],
    "children_categories": [
      {
        "id": 1055,
        "name": "Boy"
      },
      {
        "id": 1022,
        "name": "For Men"
      },
      {
        "id": 1002,
        "name": "For Women"
      },
      {
        "id": 1038,
        "name": "Girl"
      }
    ],
    "attributes_required": false,
    "max_pictures_per_item": 12,
    "max_title_length": 60,
    "max_price": null,
    "min_price": null,
    "listing_allowed": false
  },
  "1002": {
    "id": 1002,
    "name": "For Women",
    "path_from_root": [
      {
        "id": 1000,
        "name": "Clothes, Shoes and Bags"
      },
      {
        "id": 1001,
        "name": "Accessories"
      },
      {
        "id": 1002,
        "name": "For Women"
      }
    ],
    "children_categories": [
      {
        "id": 1011,
        "name": "Beanies"
      },
      {
        "id": 1008,
        "name": "Belly Dance"
      },
      {
        "id": 1007,
        "name": "Belts"
      },
      {
        "id": 1003,
        "name": "Berets"
      },
      {
        "id": 1004,
        "name": "Caps"
      },
      {
        "id": 1014,
        "name": "Gloves"
      },
      {
        "id": 1006,
        "name": "Hats"
      },
      {
        "id": 1013,
        "name": "Neckerchiefs"
      },
      {
        "id": 1015,
        "name": "Others"
      },
      {
        "id": 1016,
        "name": "Pashmina Scarves"
      },
      {
        "id": 1005,
        "name": "Scarves"
      },
      {
        "id": 1017,
        "name": "Semi Precious Jewelry"
      },
      {
        "id": 1009,
        "name": "Shawls"
      },
      {
        "id": 1020,
        "name": "Ski Caps"
      },
      {
        "id": 1010,
        "name": "Stoles"
      },
      {
        "id": 1018,
        "name": "Suspenders"
      },
      {
        "id": 1019,
        "name": "Tiaras"
      },
      {
        "id": 1012,
        "name": "Ties"
      },
      {
        "id": 1021,
        "name": "Veils"
      }
    ],
    "attributes_required": false,
    "max_pictures_per_item": 12,
    "max_title_length": 60,
    "max_price": null,
    "min_price": null,
    "listing_allowed": false
  },
  "1003": {
    "id": 1003,
    "name": "Berets",
    "path_from_root": [
      {
        "id": 1000,
        "name": "Clothes, Shoes and Bags"
      },
      {
        "id": 1001,
        "name": "Accessories"
      },
      {
        "id": 1002,
        "name": "For Women"
      },
      {
        "id": 1003,
        "name": "Berets"
      }
    ],
    "children_categories": [],
    "attributes_required": false,
    "max_pictures_per_item": 12,
    "max_title_length": 60,
    "max_price": null,
    "min_price": null,
    "listing_allowed": false
  }
  }
```

If you see, the root names are like

```
1000
1001
1002
1003
```

I would like to DeSerialize it to an object. the Strcuture below these numerics is same.

Can someone please suggest how can I generate the class for this? and Deserialize using NewtonSoft?

Note, I can't change the JSON, its very big file (about 16MB).

Comment: "an object" is pretty vague - would a dictionary work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117586/using-json-net-deserialize-to-a-property-but-has-a-numeric-name

Comment: Depending on the serializer, some support data contract which allow you the [specify a different name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) for the json and the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a Dictionary?  Post is tagged VB and C#, here is the VB:

```
Public Class Item
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property path_from_root As NameValuePair()
    Public Property children_categories As NameValuePair()
    Public Property attributes_required As Boolean
    Public Property max_pictures_per_item As Integer
    Public Property max_title_length As Integer
    Public Property max_price As Object
    Public Property min_price As Object
    Public Property listing_allowed As Boolean
End Class

Public Class NameValuePair
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property name As String
End Clas

...
Dim jstr As String = from whereever

Dim jd = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of Integer, Item))(jstr)
```

This would give you access to *all* the information by key/id.  Example:

```
Console.WriteLine("id/key: {0} name: '{1}' path0: '{2}'", jd(1003).id.ToString(),
                  jd(1003).name, jd(1003).path_from_root(0).name)
```

Output:

> id/key: 1003 name: 'Berets' path0: 'Clothes, Shoes and Bags'

---

Note that based on the data provided, `max_price` and `min_price` are Object.  If they are used at times and are numeric, `Nullable(Of Double)` might work better.

Comment: Thats it, Great! thank you for your help. It worked.

Answer (score 2):

There's a really cool feature called *Paste JSON As Classes*:

[image]

See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/12/18/paste-json-as-classes-in-asp-net-and-web-tools-2012-2-rc.aspx). Note: this is a feature that [originally came with](http://madskristensen.net/post/web-essentials-2012-released) the visual studio extension *web essenstials*. So depending on your VS version you might need to [install this extension](http://vswebessentials.com/download).

---

If you paste the first root node, it generates these classes:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public _1000 _1000 { get; set; }
}

public class _1000
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Path_From_Root[] path_from_root { get; set; }
    public Children_Categories[] children_categories { get; set; }
    public bool attributes_required { get; set; }
    public int max_pictures_per_item { get; set; }
    public int max_title_length { get; set; }
    public object max_price { get; set; }
    public object min_price { get; set; }
    public bool listing_allowed { get; set; }
}

public class Path_From_Root
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Children_Categories
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

This might be, what you need. Maybe refine it a bit.

Comment: That is a great option, however, I was not looking for this. Answer below is the correct one.